# An application named X uses too much CPU

Tags: opensuse, cpu-usage

My OS is openSUSE Leap 42.1.  When I check the System Monitor, I see an app called 'X' consumes system resources.

I right-click to see detailed info. Here is the result that is not satisfying:

```
Process 941 - X

    Sorry

    You do not have permissions to read detailed memory information about this process (/proc/941/smaps could not be read)
```

Comment: That's the X server, which runs your graphical user interface.

Comment: I think you should post it as answer. I feel relaxed. I thought I got virus because of installing non-stable and non-official program by relevant repositories. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your setup, this is very likely the X server (sometimes, it's `Xorg` rather than just `X`).

If you're doing a lot of things that requires it to work heavily, its CPU usage will go up. Sometimes, switching to a lighter window manager will help, or turning off "special effects" such as window zooming, window shadows, etc.